# modelviewer flutter No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: android, flutter, augmented-reality, model-viewer

"Access to fetch at 'https://github.com/Moeenuddin178/3dmodels/blob/e35c8f7d0c228c49232e2df61a7aab2383c116ad/CAR%20Model.glb' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:37483/model') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:37483' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.", source: http://127.0.0.1:37483/ (0)

load model from the endpoint
"https://github.com/Moeenuddin178/3dmodels/blob/e35c8f7d0c228c49232e2df61a7aab2383c116ad/CAR%20Model.glb"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to copy link of Raw model.
As in your case: https://github.com/Moeenuddin178/3dmodels/blob/e35c8f7d0c228c49232e2df61a7aab2383c116ad/CAR%20Model.glb?raw=true

Do try this once!

Comment: "Access to fetch at 'https://github.com/Moeenuddin178/3dmodels/blob/e35c8f7d0c228c49232e2df61a7aab2383c116ad/CAR%20Model.glb?raw=true' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:41693/model') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:41693' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.", source: http://127.0.0.1:41693/ (0)

Comment: Do this in manifest in application: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".

However some are also facing similar to cors problems. You can raise the issue in below link:
https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/1015

Comment: I have already used and tried but failed